# How to find Json array combination appear how many times

Tags: c#, json

My json has different toppings combination information, Need to find each toppings combination appears times.

This is just a sample json:

```
[
  {
    "toppings": [
      "pepperoni"
    ]
  },
  {
    "toppings": [
      "feta cheese"
    ]
  },
  {
    "toppings": [
      "pepperoni"
    ]
  },
  {
    "toppings": [
      "sausage",
      "beef"
    ]
  },
  {
    "toppings": [
      "sausage",
      "beef"
    ]
  },
  {
    "toppings": [
      "beef",
      "sausage"
    ]
  }
]
```

C# classes are

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string[] toppings { get; set; }
}
```

Rootobject class Counter contains how many times each combination appear in json.

"toppings": [
      "pepperoni"
    ]

Appear 2 times

"toppings": [
      "feta cheese"
    ]

Appear 1 times

{
    "toppings": [
      "sausage",
      "beef"
    ]
  }

Appear 2 times

{
    "toppings": [
      "beef",
      "sausage"
    ]
  }

Appear 1 times

---

Comment: Yes its the employment test of the Olo company. so you should do it yourself.

Comment: I would go for a Dictionary.